# Django Submit Form and keep searchresults

Tags: python, html, django

I'm using Django for a page in which the user can search for images and add them to a list. 
On the top, there is a dropdown with all available lists, and in the pages "body" there is a search form where the user can search for images by tag.

```
<form action="{% url 'qwe:search' %}" method="get">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search..." {% if query_string %} value="{{query_string}}" {% endif %}>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

On submit, the user gets the same page with a list of search results.

```
def search(request):
    query_string = request.GET["q"]
    if (query_string == None):
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()

    search_results_list = img_search(query_string, max_results=25)
    list_list = helpers.get_lists()

    context = {"search_results_list" : search_results_list, "query_string" : request.GET["q"], "lists " : list_list }
    return render(request, 'qwe/index.html', context)
```

I want the user to be able to create other lists, so I added a button next to the dropdown. When the user clicks on it, it opens a dialog (div) with a form containing an input for the new lists name.

The Problem:
What is the best way, to submit the form for creating a new list, without losing the search results?

I do this mainly for learning purposes, so every hint is welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious way that I can think of is to create an `<input type="hidden" \>` as part of your form, whose value is the `query_string`. This would allow the server to know, when it receives the form details, what the original search query was.

In fact, assuming `search_results_list` is serializable (I would guess it is, but your code gives no idea as to what is in it), you could serialize it and send that string as a hidden input - that way you are transmitting the actual search results, rather than just the query that led to them.

Comment: The hidden field works perfect, thank you. Is there a specific advantage over using sessions?

Comment: Good question - and really not sure. Obviously the hidden form input only works for that particular form submission - so if you want to store this data to access it for the user on other pages, using sessions is a better choice. Especially if you're already using a session for other purposes. But if you're not - and there was nothing in the OP to indicate you were - the hidden input avoids some of the overhead you'll have with sessions.